# How does the interpreter know when a double quoted variable ends?

Tags: php, interpreter

I'm using this code which works:

```
$this->path_medium = $this->PICTURES . "$this->file_hash-2.jpg";
```

However, I need to update it, as it is not very readable;

```
$this->file_hash
```

is  a variable.

`-2.jpg`

is a string I append to the variable.

How does the interpreter know where the variable ends and the string begins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does the interpreter know where the variable ends and the string
>   begins.

A variable not contain (-) character. like (`echo "$var-$var";`) then PHP considering file_hash as variable in this case.

From http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php

> Variable names follow the same rules as other labels in PHP. A valid variable name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by
>   any number of letters, numbers, or underscores. As a regular
>   expression, it would be expressed thus:
>   '[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*'

Answer (score 2):

The reason your code happens to work as is is because `-` is not a valid character within a variable name. PHP stops parsing the variable name at this boundary where it encounters the invalid variable name character. If you had tried to do this:

```
$this->path_medium = $this->PICTURES . "$this->file_hash2.jpg";
```

PHP would have thought `$this->file_hash2` was the variable being referenced.

There are a couple of ways to approach this. My personal preference is to not enclose the variable in quotes at all, like this:

```
$this->path_medium = $this->PICTURES . $this->file_hash . '-2.jpg';
```

You can also use `{}` around the variable for readability:

```
$this->path_medium = $this->PICTURES . "{$this->file_hash}-2.jpg";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$this->path_medium = $this->PICTURES . $this->file_hash . "-2.jpg";
```

Comment: is that answer of the question asked?

Answer (score 1):

> Additionally, how can I update this, so it is more clear?

Wrap curlies around your variables:

```
$this->path_medium = "{$this->PICTURES}{$this->file_hash}-2.jpg";
```

(or use concatenation, like you did with the first variable)

> How does the interpreter know

I assume it will stop at the first invalid character for a variable (`-` is one of them)

Comment: `{}{}`...this means concatenation ?

Comment: No, that's interpolation. Concatenation is when you put the variable outside of the string, like `$var1 . 'string'`

Answer (score 0):

Is not syntactically correct insert a variable into a string and so you have to use @Sean code else compiler can't "split" variable text.